# How to connect MySQL Workbench with google colab?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, mysql-workbench

I have MySQL Workbench installed in my local machine. I want to simultaneously fetch my SQL workbench data in Colab. So that I can apply ML algorithms on that. I am using this code,

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

user = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXX'
host = 'XXXXabcWW'
port = 'XXXXXXCV'
dbname = 'XXXX'
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=dbname, port=port)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT \* FROM table_name", conn)
print(df)
```

But is not getting connected.

I am getting error as **Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXXabcWW'**

How to correct it? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can connect mysql workbrench like this in google colab, make sure username, password, hostname & db name is correct

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password',
                              host='hostname', database='dbname')

cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name'
cursor.execute(query)

result = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Throwing me the error as  - Unknown MySQL server host 'XXXXXXXXX'

Comment: You are entering wrong host name? or Is your MySQL server is running and accepting connections?

Comment: yes,  MySQL server is running and accepting connections smoothly